# SQL Relations, Triggers and Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> In relations Doctor(SSN, First_Name, Last_Name), Clinic (ID, Name,
>   Address) and WorksFor(Doctor_SSN,Clinic_ID), add a trigger: when a
>   doctor transfer from one clinic to another clinic, file a report by
>   inserting the doctor’s first and last name as well as the old and new
>   clinic names into a doctor_transfer relation.

I would like someone to explain if the following SQL code is correct, but in addition how do triggers and foreign keys work.

### Tables

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor(
    SSN INT PRIMARY KEY,
    First_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50),
);

CREATE TABLE Clinic(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Address VARCHAR(255),
);

CREATE TABLE WorksFor(
    Doctor_SSN INT REFERENCES Doctor(SSN),
    Clinic_ID INT REFERENCES Clinic(ID)
);
```

1. In the code above, I can get a concrete picture of Doctor and Clinic tables. But how does WorksFor relation work? I sort of understand how foreign keys work from my little experience working on [Django framework](http://djangoproject.com), but other than that I have no clue what happens in the database when you create a foreign key relation. Does MySQL create a whole new table that includes **all** attributes of **both** Doctor and Clinic tables for WorksFor relation?
2. And then there are triggers. Concept is fairly easy to understand. I would only ask if you could verify that the following SQL code matches the task description above. In short, when old clinic's ID is different than new clinic's id, I create a new table that includes Doctor's first name, last name, old clinic name, new clinic name. Again I am not entirely sure how exactly foreign keys work. When I call current.Name will it give me the Clinic's name since Clinic_ID is referencing the Clinic relation? And same deal with Doctor, will the code below work or did I miss something?

### Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER DoctorTransfer(
    AFTER UPDATE ON WorksFor
    REFERENCING
        OLD ROW AS current
        NEW ROW AS new
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(current.Clinic_ID <=> new.Clinic_ID)
    INSERT INTO doctor_transfer VALUES
        VALUES(new.First_Name, new.Last_Name, current.Name as Old Clinic,
                         new.Name as New Clinic);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For #1**

> Does MySQL create a whole new table that includes all attributes of both Doctor and Clinic tables for WorksFor relation?

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says the following [emphasis mine]

> InnoDB **requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys** so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. **In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order**. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

So no it just uses indexes since FK's only care about the existance of a the key in the referenced table (Inserts into the child) or the existance of a referrer in the referring table (Delete/update of parents)

**For #2**
You have some syntax issues there.

Here's a sample trigger from the [Create Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) docs. No `REFERENCES` keyword. No `WHEN` It just directly refers to `NEW` and uses a standard `WHERE` clause

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
|
```